# Are there Xanathar Guild operations outside Waterdeep?

Tags: dnd-5e, lore, forgotten-realms, factions

I'm about to play in a game set in Baldur's Gate, and the DM's running the adventure are sticklers for the canon with little leeway.

In D&D Faerun lore, do thieves' guilds, the Xanathar Guild specifically, canonically have agents and safe-houses, and or interests in other cities around the Sword Coast?

I assume there may be. After all, if something is worth stealing, it should be stolen, and there may be very valuable opportunities outside Waterdeep, too.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Comment: I see you've tagged the question for fifth edition. I assume from that you'll be *playing* 5e; is it important whether or not the information/lore is from 5e or not? (I.e. if you're trying to play a game in DR1492, that might devalue pre-5e material.) Or is lore from any era useful?

Answer (score 6):

Quoting from the 3e *FR Campaign Setting* (page 281):

> The Xanathar's Guild is a group of thieves and cutthroats operating out of the bowels of Waterdeep. From its main offices in Skullport, the Xanathar's Guild has access to several *portals*, with prominent ones leading to an alley in Waterdeep, a rock outcropping near Calimport, and a small Guild-owned warehouse in Westgate.

And from the novel *Dawn of Night*:

> ... the Xanathar had reached an agreement with the First Lord of Hillsfar regarding the use of the portal: demihumans, and other undesirables in Hillsfar, were escorted by Xanathar agents from the First Lord's dungeons to Skullport's slave pens ...

So it would be reasonable to assume that, **yes, they have interests in other cities**. However, to the best of my knowledge, unlike the Red Wizards or the Black Network, Xanathar's Guild has never been described as a pan-Faerûn organization in Realms lore. Thieves' guilds, slaver rings, and other crime organisations each have their own domains and do not want interlopers; imagine the Corleones getting a foothold in Las Vegas, for example. Just the fact that there are valuable opportunities outside Waterdeep, does not mean that an organization can go and grab them.